# Is my servo fried?

Tags: arduino, battery, rcservo

I got a new servo a few days back (RC Servo, Futaba FP-S148). I first tested it out with the Sweep sketch on Arduino, powering it with the Arduino 5v and GND pins only. It was working, just fine.

Today I was trying to use it in my robot and I tried powering it with 2 LiPo batteries (Samsung ICR16850 2200mAh, from an old laptop battery) connected in series, giving 8.32v. As soon as I connected my servo, it started rotating randomly, I had not connected it to my Arduino yet. I quickly took it out.

Next, I used a L7805 to get 5.13v regulated supply out of my batteries that I used earlier. When I connected my batteries to the servo, and the servo to the Arduino, uploaded the sketch, the servo started behaving rather strangely, it first did a complete turn and then stopped. Only a humming sound came from the servo. Strange thing is, whenever I connect one of my Multimeter leads to the power cables, the servo immediately turned in the opposite direction **only as long as only lead was in contact with either the positive or negative wire**.
Otherwise, the servo just gives a humming sound.

Have I fried my servo? Or is it some other issue?

**UPDATE 1**
I stripped down the servo and checked the motor. It is working fine, seems like this is a gear problem.

Comment: What code are you using to control the servo? Are you using the Arduino Servo library or something similar?

Comment: @Octopus I'm using the sweep example sketch

Comment: Did you ever try putting it back on the Arduino 5V and ground??

Comment: @Chuck yes I did... It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's absolutely fried. Check the tech specs of your servo next time.

> Power requirement: 4.8V or 6V (from receiver)
>   Power consumption: 6V 8mA (at idle)

Comment: Time to buy a new one I guess